# Android Show Images while maintaining Aspect Ratio

Tags: java, android, image, aspect-ratio

I am working on an App which shows images (by capturing using camera or choose from gallery) in some activity. The problem I am facing is showing images of different sizes. The actual size of image is very big even those which are captured by camera of same phone are large in size. So if I show them in an ImageView the get stretched.

I have seen in some apps like Facebook, when image is displayed in Full Screen mode, it maintains the aspect ratio I guess. The whole image, whatever its size may be, is shown in the screen but it doesn't get stretched. The image automatically adjusts its height and width as per the need. How to achieve the same functionality?

How to make ImageView which would be able to adjust its height and width (maximum already defined) as per the need.

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/defaultimage"
        android:padding="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a different `android:scaleType` in your layout.  The [`ImageView.ScaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) documentation lists the different ones that are available.  It sounds like you probably want to change `matrix` to `fitCenter` in your example.